The emulator process has terminated after updating Android studio
After apdating Android Studio to the latest version Koala feature drop, when I run AVD i get the error: The emulator process has terminated.
When i run in cmd I got this:
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 3224
INFO    | Android emulator version 35.1.20.0 (build_id 12234392) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Graphics backend: gfxstream
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-35\google_apis\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 1252
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): AndroidVirtualizationFramework
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 192.168.43.1
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 50ee:6870:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 50ee:6870:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 28f4:6870:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 28f4:6870:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 8fa:6870:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 8fa:6870:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 800:6970:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 800:6970:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 380e:6970:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 380e:6970:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 4814:6970:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 4814:6970:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 901a:6970:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 901a:6970:a401:0:50ee:6870:a401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Critical:
INFO    | Warning:
INFO    | Warning:  (6x)
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
library_mode host gpu mode host

Does someone know how to solve this?

Attempt to duplicate the emulator. Navigate to the device manager. Click on the ellipsis (three dots) located next to the emulator's name. From the options that appear, choose 'duplicate'.  click 'finish'. Subsequently, initiate the newly created emulator. Please be aware that the initialization process might take a few moments

I did that but didn't solved the problem. I only could start emulator after editing in AVD graphics to software, ram to 512 and multi-core CPU to 1. Then it would work for a while then again the problem with the emulator process has terminated would appear.

I had the same problem and fixed it by deleting the SDK folder located at C:\Users\Your UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. Then, I redownloaded it in Android Studio.

I managed to solve this problem after a long time after running the command -feature -Vulkan.
I got the error

ERROR | Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

This advice helped me: Android Studio error: cannot connect to daemon
I ran these commands in the command line:
net stop winnat
net start winnat

